# Can Kill streak kits (Professional and Specialized) be applied to Strange weapons?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I want to make some of my strange weapons kill streak weapons, but do I need to find a specific kill streak stating Strange, or do I just need to input a strange weapon into the list of items needed instead of a normal one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, killstreak kits can be applied to any quality of weapons.

> Killstreak Kits can be applied to weapons of any quality.

[Source](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Killstreak_Kit)

Answer (score 4):

Killstreak kits can be used on strange weapons, and you can use the same killstreak kit as  a regular, normal weapon would use. All you have to do is apply the kit (Professional or Specialized) to the strange weapon, you don't need a need a specific killstreak fabricator for strange weapons, as there isn't one that exists.

Answer (score 1):

The professional or specialized fabricator should indicate specifically which weapon it can be applied to. You must first complete the fabricator in order to get a kit, by completing all the ingredients of the fabricator. Once you finish the fabricator, you should receive a kit. That kit can only be applied to the specific weapon that was stated when you got your fabricator. It can be applied to any type of that weapon (unique, vintage, genuine, strange, festive, festive strange, collector's, etc.). To use the kit, just click on it in your inventory, and click the use bottom on the bottom. Then find the weapon you can apply it to.